# How to automate downloading a files using java program

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, user-interface

I need to download files with multiple links from a page (may be more than 100 files with separate links) automatically. I know the URL to login and I have credentials.

I'm willing to do this in Java program by automation. The only way to go to the downloading location page is through login to the site.

Is cURL command helpful to this?

Please advise me to do this.

Comment: I take it we are talking about HTTP. Just use standard HTTP connection logic? Not sure what the "problem" is. I would definately **not** use cURL as it is system-specific (I'm assuming you want to use the command line version)

Comment: @Nablex : I think, she needs to automate the downloading through HTTP connection.

Comment: Ok but I still don't see the issue... Scrape the links, loop over them and download them one at a time using standard http logic? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: @nablex: if there are button clicks or links to be clicked for each file downloads, then it is definitely a problem isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use wget which can download log files:

```
wget -r --no-parent --user=user --password=password --no-check-certificate <URL>
```

- You can pass headers in --header, e.g. --header "Cookie: JSONSESSIONID=3433434343434"
- you can pass post data using --post-data 'email=$EMAIL&password=$PASSWRD'

Or You can use following HttpClient in java:

- Here is examples of [HTTPClient](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/) for login and passing POST/GET/Headers information
- First get whole HTML page as String
- Either parse that String to get links for files or convert to java objects using XML to Object mappers like https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml
- Once you get the links of files to download files using HttpClient

> ```
> public void saveFile(String url, String FileName) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
>             HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
>             HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
>             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
>             if (entity != null) {
>                 long len = entity.getContentLength();
>                 InputStream is = entity.getContent();
>                 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)));
>                 IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
>             }
>             return;
>         }
> ```

Comment: OP has more than one links in that page to download

Comment: @Sn. What can I use if there are more parameters to be taken? For example, not only username and password, also needed other parameter call agentID, but I don't know what is the 3rd parameter's key.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to copy a file from a site to a local file then you can use java.nio.file

```
Files.copy(new URL("http://host/site/filename").openStream(), Paths.get(localfile)
```

Comment: OP has more than one links in that page to download

Comment: @Jackcob: I don't know even the filename. Whatever files it contains, I needed to download it. And needed to give authentication too